# Cloning a mercurial repository via SSH

Tags: mercurial, ssh, repository, clone

My home directory is on one server, and Mercurial repository in on another. I would like to clone the repository to my home directory. We connect to the other server via ssh. How can I clone mercurial repository?

My local repository should be in: `/home/my_user/my_project`

Hg Repository is (on another server) in: `/opt/Application/hg/the_project`

Best Regards

Answer (score 5):

According to `hg help urls` :

```
- path is relative to the remote user's home directory by default. Use an
  extra slash at the start of a path to specify an absolute path:

    ssh://example.com//tmp/repository
```

So, to download from your remote location, you must do :

```
hg clone ssh://<ip-address>//opt/Application/hg/the_project
```

(note the double `/` after the ip address !)

Comment: Thanks - and apparently (with hg version 1.4.3) a triple slash works just fine too!  E.g., `hg clone ssh://user@host///home/user/repo`

Answer (score 1):

I tried the following:

```
hg clone ssh://(other server name):/opt/Application/hg/the_project
```

but it will only go to my home directory.  However, if you were to make a symbolic link (`ln -s`) in your home directory to the repository directory, it will clone it just fine (works best if you have keys set up so you don't have to type the password in each time to connect)

Comment: I will type the IP address of the other machine. do I need to write `hg clone ssh://11.11.11.111:/opt/Application/hg/the_project` ?

Comment: You can read my answer for a reason why the clone is "restricted" to your home directory. There's no need to create a symbolic link at all.

Comment: Cool - I did not know about the double slash.